# How to stop infinite cell color in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I open an empty Excel sheet, select the entire row '10' and click on fill color 'yellow'. Now the entire row '10' is colored yellow.
Then I notice that I actually need the yellow colored cells only up to column 'X'. To solve this "problem", I select the entire row '10', click on fill color 'No Fill', select the cells 'A10' to 'X10' and click on fill color 'yellow'. Now only cells 'A10' to 'X10' are colored yellow and all other cells are with the fill color 'No Fill'.
But if you have hundreds of rows colored in different colors, suddenly it's not so easy anymore, because you would have to do this for each individual row separately.

In older versions of Excel or if you save the Excel file as .xls, you can select all columns from column 'Y' to 'IV' (last column in older versions of Excel) and then set the fill color to 'No Fill'.
But in today's versions of Excel you've more or less unlimited columns, so this approach doesn't work anymore.
Note: If you open a file, where you've done this approach, with a new version of Excel, you will suddenly see the original colors to the right of column 'IV' again.

So my question; is there a possibility to tell Excel that all cells after column 'X' must be with the fill color 'No Fill'?

Comment: What are the changes that result in needing to colour different cells? Conditional formatting is most likely what you need to use but it is difficult from your question to know what form it would take. It could be as simple as if the cell is not empty give it a colour, or you might reference the header row if that changes.

Comment: XSLX has not unlimited columns. Only 16384. Is your issue about selecting all these columns manually by mouse? If yes, just select the first column and then press `[CTRL] + [SHIFT] + [RIGHT]`.

Comment: Okay, great. Indeed, this really allows me to select the cells I need. Thank you very much for your hint. However, I still hope there's a way to stop the infinite cell color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now solved my "problem" with the following VBA macro:

```vb
Public Sub Remove_Infinite_Cell_Colors()
  Dim Row As Long
  Dim Column As Long
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim LastColumn As Long
  Dim BackgroundColor() As Long
  Dim BackgroundPattern() As Long

  LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  LastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

  ReDim BackgroundColor(LastColumn) As Long
  ReDim BackgroundPattern(LastColumn) As Long

  For Row = 1 To LastRow
    For Column = 1 To LastColumn
      BackgroundColor(Column) = Cells(Row, Column).Interior.Color
      BackgroundPattern(Column) = Cells(Row, Column).Interior.Pattern
    Next

    Rows(Row).Interior.Pattern = xlNone

    For Column = 1 To LastColumn
      Cells(Row, Column).Interior.Color = BackgroundColor(Column)
      Cells(Row, Column).Interior.Pattern = BackgroundPattern(Column)
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

This macro sets the color of all rows to 'No Fill' and then colors each cell with the color it had before.

Answer (score 2):

> In older versions of Excel or if you save the Excel file as .xls, you can select all >columns from column 'Y' to 'IV' (last column in older versions of Excel) and then set >the fill color to 'No Fill'.
> But in today's versions of Excel you've more or less unlimited columns, so this >approach doesn't work anymore.

You can select the first column you want to have no fill the use cntrl+shift+right arrow to extend the selection to all the columns to the right and then select no fill just the same way as you did in the older versions of excel.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that works. Thank you very much for your hint. But this is again just a workaround, so I'll have the same problem when a future Excel version will be available which support more than 16384 columns. It would be really great if there's a way to stop the infinite cell color.

Comment: Well the conditional formatting on all cells with formula =IF(COLUMN(A1)>3,1,0) and format set to no colour works.  Just replace 3 in the formula with the number of the first column not to be coloured

Comment: It is unlikely that Excel will extend its columns past 16384.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Named Range using relative references.

For example, you want cells `Axxx:Xxxx` (where "xxx" is the row number) to get the color, but not to affext any other cells in the row (columns past column X).

So, pick a row for this part of the work. Perhaps you pick row 13. Select ("highlight") cell `A13`. Create a Named Range (however you prefer) and name it so you will remember its name. Actually, something that alphabetizes near the start of any alphabetized list is best:  something starting with an "_" or "AA" perhaps.

For the `Refers to` box, enter the following:

```
=$B13:$X13,$A13
```

Just copy and paste that. When you save it, Excel will add the sheet name, but no worries about that, and why go to the effort, maybe getting it wrong, yourself? Just let Excel do it.

Do it precisely like the above example:

1. Add NO extra "$" in the addresses. The ROW is to be `Relative` so where it acts changes to match the row you are in, but to always select the same columns rather than always affecting only one exact set of cells. Don't take any `$`out either!
2. Do NOT NOT NOT figure to "simplify" and make the range "A13:X13". Whatever cell is listed LAST will be the cell selected any time you select the Named Range and I'm sure you do NOT want that to be the column X cell! (This is "Excel using a screwy Windows feature" and not unique to Excel.)

Now, how does this help you?

To the left of the editing bar (where you edit a formula if you press `F2`) is a box in which you usually see the address of the cell you currently have selected. This is actually a dropdown box that gives you a list of the available Named Ranges. If you click the dropdown's little "down" triangle at the right of the box, you see that list and now you see why I suggested selecting a name that would appear at or near the top.

If you select that Name, Excel will select a range of the columns you care about for the row your current selected cell is in. So if in row 2398, it will select A2398:X2398. If you used the range as above, cell A2398 would be the currently selected cell. Start in a different row and it will be that different row in which those columns' cells are selected.

The reason you used `$` for the letter part of the cells in the `Refers to` box is so the same columns will be used no matter what cell you have selected when you click the Name. So if in column FFG when you click it, you will still select A:X, not FFG:...something.

Now make your color change. Then do your work.

One more useful thing:  IF you want to make a color change, then move to some other row and make another color change (in other words, no OTHER work in between, rather you just want to color up rows 3, 54, 85, 88, 202, and 342 and you will select the range, color, move to the next row you see needs done, select the range, color, etc.), you can select the first row's cells and do the coloring, and move to the next row you see needs done or is on your list. Select the range again but this time save a ton of keystrokes by pressing either `Ctrl-Y` or `F4` and your last action (the coloring up) will be repeated. This will not work for data entry, usually, but it does for actions like formatting. So, one click, one press, that row's done and you're on to the next.

Comment: Very detailed and thorough. However, can you point out how doing this is superior to the much simpler answer already provided?

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed description. But does this really solve my problem? With your instructions I can easily select the cells I actually need to color, what's really cool. But if you have hundreds of rows colored in different colors, you still have to do this separately for each row which has a different color, don't you?